# How can I access backward compatible Xbox 360 games from the store, on the Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network, backwards-compatibility

As of now, Operation Flashpoint: Dragon Rising is available for free with Xbox Live Gold. Operation Flashpoint is an Xbox 360 game, but it was ported to Xbox One via [backwards compatibility](http://www.xbox.com/sk-SK/xbox-one/backward-compatibility).

How can I access Xbox 360 games from the store, via Xbox One?

Comment: If OP sees this comment, my answer is no longer valid. If you could 'unaccept' the answer, I would like to remove it, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is easy, as of March 2016:

As of the [March 2016 update](https://majornelson.com/2016/03/23/system-updates-buy-xbox-360-games-on-xbox-one-16-person-party-chat-and-more/), the Xbox store has an "Xbox 360" section, allowing you to access backwards compatible Xbox 360 games directly from your Xbox One. Keep in mind that **the Xbox One can only access Xbox 360 games that are backwards compatible**.

## Something to note, concerning Games for Gold:

If you have Xbox Gold, and wish to take full advantage of the "Games for Gold" freebies, it is worth considering that any game that is not *yet* supported by the Xbox One will not be accessible through this means. You still have other options to 'purchase' the non-compatible games, while they are free, in anticipation of the games later becoming supported.

## If you have an Xbox 360:

Too easy. Simply log in to the store from your Xbox 360, and make the purchases from there. From an Xbox 360 you will have access to the entire Xbox 360 library, available to your region. You can also be signed in to an Xbox 360 **at the same time** as your Xbox One, so you can run it through your Xbox Ones 'HDMI in', to make life easier. If you are borrowing a console for this purpose, you can opt to require password at each sign in, if you have worries about illegitimate access to your account.

## If you have no way to access the store from an Xbox 360, and the game is not yet available for backwards compatibility:

Log in to the [Xbox Store](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/) from a computer, sign in to your email account, and purchase the game from there. **Ensure that you are accessing the right Xbox store for your location. The above link is the English store, and other stores may vary in content and compatibility.**

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, you are so kind :) Well I have difficulties with buying game ( 0 price ) from marketplace.xbox.com. It always ends with an Error, something like "We are sorry, but transaction can't be realized, Do it again"

Comment: Google "xbox marketplace" and follow the official link from there. I come from Australia, and we have a different marketplace to the UK or America. You might have an issue if it trys to access it from a different market. Also ensure you are logged in

Comment: The old "go to a mates and use his 360" trick works, too. I feel this may not be an option, but have included information for future users.

Comment: I suppose I am using marketplace correctly, it automatically redirects me to Slovak version. I have no difficulties when I am buyng from Store, but Marketplace won't let me. I will contact technical support.
That tip with mates 360 is great.

Thanks you for helping me with this :)

Comment: So I had chat with official support, where they told me, there is no possibility to get current backawards compatible Live Gold free games for Xbox 360, on Xbox One, without Xbox 360. 

So only solution is, find some Xbox 360, purchase game there, then you can install it on Xbox One.

Dissapointed..

Comment: I have since confirmed my answer is outdated. More to the point, they have removed the ability to access the marketplace without an Xbox 360.

Comment: I just tried to download compatible Borderlands through the old store ( web interface ), it was successfull! So now, it is possible to download Gold Live XBOX 360 games even without having Xbox 360. Finally :)

Comment: I would just like to note that this answer (and others like it) are now outdated.  With the most current Xbox One update, you can now purchase backwards compatible titles directly from the games store on the Xbox One console itself.

Comment: @Ryan, cheers. I thought of this when the update rolled out, but cbf rolling back and finding it